# Trying to make machine learning code with python. but i get error when first epoch finishes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

i am trying to make machine learning model that reads images. but getting error when first epoch finishes.

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 147456 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 12544
any ideas?

```
validation_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_data_gen = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df,
    #directory="CatDog",   
    x_col="images",
    y_col="label",
    class_mode="binary",
    batch_size=64,
    target_size=(128,128))

validation_data_gen = validation_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df,
    #directory='',
    x_col="images",
    y_col="label",
    class_mode="binary",
    batch_size=64,
    target_size=(64,64))

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128,128,3)),
    MaxPool2D((2,2)),
    Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPool2D((2,2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPool2D((2,2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(train_data_gen, epochs=2, validation_data=validation_data_gen)
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both the data and the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are your full code.
There are already some problem.

1. line1:`rescale=1./255`
   `rescale=1./255` will make your image from "0~255 8bit int image" to "0~1 float image". So be sure that your training data, validation data and test data in the same format. That is you may want to rescale train_generator as well.
2. line19:`target_size=(64,64)`
   It may be better to use the same `target_size`. If original sizes of images are large enough, set `target_size` not small than `input_shape` of your model to avoid resizing images multiple times. It may lose some information of your images.
3. line33:`Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`
   The last `Dense layer` is usually your classification layer. Setting `Dense(1, ...)` means the number of your label is only 1. If you want to classify the image is cat or dog, you may set `Dense(2, ...)`.
   `activation='sigmoid'` will give you like a percentage of how much the model thinks the image matching the label.
   You may want to use `activation='softmax'` to give you a result of classification.

Basically, I guessed, the error is caused by wrong Dense(unit, ...).